# Using videojs-watermark with video.js in a Vue app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, video.js

I am trying to make an incredibly simple page in Vue with a watermarked video player. I've managed to successfully use video.js to make the video player, but I've been unable to get videojs-watermark to work.

Here is the VideoPlayer.vue component page

```
<template>
  <div>
    <video
    controls
    preload="auto"
    
     ref="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-theme-city"></video>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  @import 'https://unpkg.com/video.js@7/dist/video-js.min.css';
  @import 'https://unpkg.com/@videojs/themes@1/dist/city/index.css';
</style>

<script>
import videojs from 'video.js';
import watermark from 'videojs-watermark';

export default {
  name: 'VideoPlayer',
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {};
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      player: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    videojs.registerPlugin('watermark', watermark);

    this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, this.options, () => {
      this.player.log('onPlayerReady', this);
    });
    this.player.watermark({
    file: 'src/assets/Watermark.png',
    xpos: 50,
    ypos: 50,
    xrepeat: 1,
    opacity: 0.5,
    })  
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.dispose();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In this the video player works, but the watermark doesn't.

On this line
`import watermark from 'videojs-watermark';`
I get the following warning:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'videojs-watermark'. 'e:/Georg HDD Backup/Level 6/Apprenticeship/VidDistribProto/node_modules/videojs-watermark/es5/plugin.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/videojs-watermark` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'videojs-watermark';`Vetur(7016)

I've tried the solutions the warning presents, but `npm i --save-dev @types/videojs-watermark` coughs up an error and creating a folder in @types with a .d.ts file shuts the warning up but the watermark still doesn't show up.

What else can I try?

Thanks a lot!